# Defining a function with three parameters that if b squared minus 4ac is negative it returns false

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have tried several different variations of this code and it keeps telling me is something is wrong with the syntax and I might just need some fresh eyes to see it.

```
def hasRealSolution(a,b,c):
    if b**2 - (4*a*c) <0:
        return False
else:
    return True
```

Comment: You need to indent your last two lines.

Comment: If you keep being told that something is wrong then read that message and try to understand what exactly is wrong.

Comment: @zamuz: Don't edit the error out of the OPs code.

Answer (score 1):

First, fix your indentation.

Second, the comparison already returns a boolean value; you do not need the `if`:

```
def has_real_solution(a, b, c):
    return b*b - 4*a*c >= 0
```